# Finding max- average error in R programming

Tags: r, numeric, numerical-methods

It's a simple question but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a data set. I found the least-square line .when I write `summary(lm(data_y~data_x))` I can find std.error but I don't know how to find max error or average error in R programming. Is there a function to find them or where did I make mistake or what should I do?

Comment: Are you talking about the Residual Standard Error or Multiple R Squared?

Comment: I can also found both residual standard error and multiple r square with summary commend. However, the question wanted to find max and average error. might residual standard error and multiple r square are the same with max and average error?

Comment: So, I think what you want to ask is about the variability of your residuals in your linear model. 

You can do this by calling `sigma('your_lm_model_name')` which will give back the residual standard error (which can also be seen by the `summary` function). 

This is the "max error" as you would call it, because it uses the F statistics to compare the variability of the lm's fitted values(numerator) to the variability of it's residuals (denominator)

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: useful comments should be upvoted by OP! My pleasure!